# Powershell Substring replacement

Tags: regex, string, powershell, substring

Folks

I am unable to replace the below string in PowerShell, initially I suspected it to be due to regexp and used `[regex]::Escape()` to resolve the `\` to double slash however it still does not work. Can you please suggest?

```
PS C:\User>"C:clog" -replace "C:c" , ""
PS C:\User>log
PS C:\User>"C:\\c\\log" -replace "C:\\c\\", ""
PS C:\User>C:\\c\\log
```

Comment: You defined 2 backslashes in the input string, so you need 4 in the pattern: `"C:\\c\\log" -replace "C:\\\\c\\\\", ""`

Comment: Wiktor you are right i achieved this now with another [regex]::Escape() over the input string. Please post in answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Split-Path`, it is designed for this:

```
Split-Path "C:\\c\\log" -Leaf

# returns "log"
```

Comment: Nope its not just about extracting log i have stuff like C:\\c\\log\\loggin\\logo

Comment: You can stick with the regexp if it's more adapted to your case, then.